# Javascript april fools if statement Website

Tags: javascript, css

I'm trying to add a new class to my body, but only on April fools.
I can't get it to work since I have very little experience with Javascript.
Here is my code:

```
if (new Date().getMonth() == 4 && getDate == 1) {
    document.body.classList.add("pils");
}
```

What do I need to change in order to make it function correctly?

Comment: `if (new Date().getMonth() == 3 && new Date().getDate() == 1)` months in JavaScript work differently, here January means 0 and so on.

Answer (score 1):

The [getMonth()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Date/getMonth) method returns the month in the specified date according to local time, as a zero-based value (where zero indicates the first month of the year).

```js
// Month will be 3, because started from 0
if (new Date().getMonth() == 3 && new Date().getDate() == 1) {
    document.body.classList.add("pils");
}

//use reusable date object
var mydate = new Date();
if (mydate.getMonth() == 3 && mydate.getDate() == 1) {
    document.body.classList.add("pils-new");
}
```